# How do I force a theme to use Wordpress's jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I installed a new awesome theme and got it working after hard work. Everything's running fine, except the 'Add Media', 'Add Link' and the 'HTML Editor'.

I read how to diagnose the problem according the official diagnosing instructions and posted it on Wordpress.org forum as they told me to, but I got no response yet and I don't think I'll be getting one anyway.

I used this:

```
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

And it did solve the problem for 'Add Media' and 'HTML Editor', but not for the 'add link'. When I click it, it DOES open, but the screen goes grey and the box is way far in the bottom-left corner and and I can't close it with the 'Cancel' button ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXKHj.png)).

I did try disabling all the plugins but it doesn't work ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkPtC.png)).

In summary the problem is that the theme probably has its own version of jQuery and Wordpress 3.5 has its own. How do I force the theme to use Wordpress's jQuery? Or force Wordpress to use the theme's jQuery? Anything that will fix the editor, I want that.

EDIT: Just to make it clearer. There is NO conflict with plugins. The conflict is between Wordpress's jQuery and the theme's jQuery.

If it helps, this is in the header file.

```
    <?php
    wp_enqueue_style("jqueryui_css", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/css/jqueryui/custom.css", false, $pp_theme_version, "all");
    wp_enqueue_style("screen_css", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/css/screen.css", false, $pp_theme_version, "all");
    wp_enqueue_style("tipsy_css", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/css/tipsy.css", false, $pp_theme_version, "all");
    wp_enqueue_style("fancybox_css", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css", false, $pp_theme_version, "all");
    wp_enqueue_style("flexslider_css", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/flexslider/flexslider.css", false, $pp_theme_version, "all");

    $pp_advance_enable_responsive = get_option('pp_advance_enable_responsive');

    if(!empty($pp_advance_enable_responsive))
    {
        wp_enqueue_style("grid_css", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/css/grid.css", false, $pp_theme_version, "all");
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['pp_slider_style']))
    {
        $pp_slider_style = $_SESSION['pp_slider_style'];
    }
    else
    {
        $pp_slider_style = get_option('pp_slider_style');
    }

    if($pp_slider_style=='full')
    {
        wp_enqueue_style("pp_slider_style", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/css/fullslide.css", false, $pp_theme_version, "all");
    }
    wp_enqueue_style("colorpicker.css", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css", false, $pp_theme_version, "all");
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<?php   
    wp_enqueue_script("jquery", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/jquery.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("jQuery_UI_js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/jquery-ui.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("swfobject.js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/swfobject/swfobject.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("colorpicker.js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/colorpicker.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("eye.js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/eye.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("utils.js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/utils.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("fancybox_js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("jQuery_easing", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/jquery.easing.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("jQuery_hint", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/hint.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("jQuery_validate", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/jquery.validate.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("jQuery_tipsy", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/jquery.tipsy.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("reflection_js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/reflection.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("browser_js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/browser.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("flexslider_js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("marquee_js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/jquery.marquee.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("jwplayer_js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/jwplayer.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("gmap_js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/gmap.js", false, $pp_theme_version);
    wp_enqueue_script("custom_js", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/custom.js", false, $pp_theme_version);

    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
?>
```

Comment: Without sharing any code, it's highly likely nobody understands your concrete problem. From what you describe there can be a million things that go wrong.

Comment: In general if you've asked your question elsewhere ("cross-posting") please hyperlink to it, so we can see if it has been answered prior to answering it here. Doing so routinely helps reduce duplicate effort.

Comment: What theme is it that you've installed? Does the author offer forum/IRC support?

Comment: Related Q&A at **WordPress StackExchange**: [*How to solve a conflict between a plugin and a theme?*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/77772/12615). :::::: To make answers possible, you need add to your Question ([edit]) how this theme is dequeueing and enqueueing jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// only for Themes since WordPress 3.0
function jquery_190() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) { // actually not necessary, because the Hook only get used in the Theme
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // unregistered key jQuery
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js', false, '1.9.0'); // register key jQuery with URL of Google CDN
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); // include jQuery
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'jquery_190' ); // Theme active, include function
```

[MORE INFO](http://wpengineer.com/2028/small-tips-using-wordpress-and-jquery/)

Comment: e.g. functions.php in the template... the functions.php behaves like a normal plugin but it is activated when theme is activated...

Comment: I seriously don't know how to thank you enough! Everything's working fine except the 'Add Link' but I can just manage that through the <a href> It's an editor plugin issue. The console shows,                                       Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wpdialog' editor_plugin.js:1                                                     It's not necessary to fix, but hey, it will help. Many THANKS. I knew asking on Stackoverflow was worth it!

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this discussion](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-want-to-disable-jquery-included-in-wordpress) on wordpress forums that explore the reasons, why this is done as it is and what are available workarounds.

This is what has worked for me:

```
// Include this in functions.php or the theme
if( !is_admin()){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"), false, '1.9.0');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```