# TinyMCE visual editor hyperlink button not working in WordPress 3.5

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, tinymce

When i click the insert hyperlin button in the visual editor it literally does nothing. I ran the console in IE to see any errors which i've listed below...

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'wpdialog'

editor_plugin.js?ver=358-23224, line 1 character 471
```

does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

any help most appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe some plugin is interfering with the TinyMCE. Try disabling other plugins and check if the error persists.

Comment: i deactivated every plugin and still does not work :(

Comment: Is the problem only in IE?

Comment: no its chrome and IE so far, so i'm assuming all browsers

Answer (score 2):

I found this [WordPress forum post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-31-problem-insertedit-link-button?replies=30) which seems to deal with the similar issue you are having.

There are few proposed solutions in it, so you might find it useful.

Another thing you could check is if jQuery is referenced twice.

Comment: Are you using this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/ ? Maybe you should try this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/ - That TinyMCE Advanced has few users in there with same problem as you but no solution, while TinyMCE Advanced doesn't seem to have this problem (looking at issues users are having)

Comment: Since it is not working in Chrome, you could use Tools > Developer Tools and choose "Source tab". Then reload the page when you are in Visual Editor and check bottom right corner for red x icon which will indicate javascript errors. Click on that icon to see list of errors. This might give you clues what the problem is. I know you did that in IE, but maybe Chrome will give you some additional info.

Comment: ok did that and it gave me this message...

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wpdialog' editor_plugin.js:1
tinymce.create.open editor_plugin.js:1
i.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) tiny_mce.js:1
(anonymous function) editor_plugin.js:1
k.create.execCommand tiny_mce.js:1
i.onclick tiny_mce.js:1
(anonymous function) tiny_mce.js:1
j tiny_mce.js:1
y

Comment: Sorry, I'm not javascript expert so can't help you much more. I still suspect that the jQuery might be referenced twice in your site. There are some similar questions about this specific error like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427507/how-do-i-force-a-theme-to-use-wordpresss-jquery and this one also deals with referencing jQuery. You could also ask your problem in WordPress Support Forum for that plugin.

Comment: i fixed it... it turned all the plugins off and on again for the second time just to double check and it worked, i dont understand why it didn't work the first time, i must have done something wrong. thanks for your helps guys :)

Answer (score -1):

In order for link to work, include the "wordpress" in the list of plugins to load in TinyMCE. For instance in the settings or tinymce.init({...}) initialization object you would add: 
plugins : "paste wplink media wordpress"

Whenever you select some text then click the link icon, a small popup window opens to let you enter the URL in a text box.